# Get image source from an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a page on a website that is just an image tag. When the page is loaded, it makes an API call and changes the source of the image depending what picture is available that day. For example, after an API call has been made (with an example picture):

```
 <head>
   <body>
     <img src="http://www.tizag.com/pics/htmlT/sunset.gif"/>
   </body>
 </head>
```

My goal is to be able to use the URL of the page with just the image as the source of an image on any other page. Other sites would then be able to use the URL of the page with the image.

In other words, how would I take the source of the image on the page above and use it is the source of an image on a different page?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: You could have your server make the API call, and store the result. And then all your pages can query your server for the image.

Comment: i don't know that site source you means! (you said it different page) , but i'm sure ts not possible to get it from HTML code , you have to see javascript codes and understand what's going on there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I completely understand Your issue, but can't You just use the same source URL on other pages?
Maybe You want to have reference to that image so when You want to change this image on all pages You wouldn't have to do this on all pages but just one. Then it would be simpler to just replace file.
I think you should use javascript script that would be verifying which image should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the same API to get the source on the other site?

If you can't:
First, get the XML from the image-only-site and parse it as DOM elements.
Next, get the `img` element's source.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your-url', success: function(data) {
        var xmlString = data, parser = new DOMParser(),
            doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
        var src = doc.firstChild.src;
    }
});
```

Comment: No, I can't. Unfortunately the API requires a decent amount of code to parse, and it would be preferable to simplify it a bit. This sounds like a very reasonable solution. I will attempt to implement it later tonight or tomorrow and get back to you. Thank you very much!